# CSS flexible layout: flexible left column and variable fixed right column

Tags: html, css

I want to display the content of the div element in a single row. However the width of the ul element is unknown because it can have a number of child li elements. The h2 would always occupy the rest of the space. each li element has a width of 20px.

It would look something like this:

```
|----h2------------|li|li|li||
|----h2---------------|li|li||
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<h2>name</h2>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have found numerous solutions on the internet but not sure which to choose (proper solution vs hacks). browser compatibility is not an issue, it only needs to work on the latest version of chrome.

Update:
There will be multiple rows of div elements and the li elements should align.

Comment: It would be useful to know which methods you've seen that don't meet your needs so that you don't get answers repeating what you already know doesn't work.

Comment: I tried the flexbox method (it seems to do what I needed) but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest, most compact and straight forward way is to use floats.  If you know your elements will be different sizes, but you don't know exactly what they will be, there are 2 completely flexible ways to go about this.

This would be how to do it using `display: table`:

http://jsfiddle.net/8uTfp/1/

```
div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

h1, ul {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul {
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This would be how to do it using flexbox:

http://jsfiddle.net/8uTfp/

```
div {
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  margin-left: auto;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the examples. There's one condition where the width of the div is <300px. Is it possible to make the ul part directly below h2 with pure CSS? (<300px h2 ul stacked, >=300px one row)

Comment: Yes and no.  Here's the styles to do so:  http://jsfiddle.net/8uTfp/3/.  But this won't work in any Mozilla browser because they haven't implemented wrapping at all.  Even worse, they've decided to go unprefixed in their upcoming versions (it's coming "later", though).

Answer (score 1):

You could float the `h2` left, and the `ul` right.

```
div h2 { float: left; }
div ul { float: right; }
```

Comment: The only trouble with floats is lining up the elements vertically and they have different font-sizes.  You have to know the font-size and line-height for the elements involved and do a bit of math to line them up:  http://jsfiddle.net/8uTfp/2/

Answer (score -1):

If the div's height and the list items' height are fixed and known values, you could try the followihg CSS (notice I added css classes):

```
.container{
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.container ul{
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  /* Other reset rules here ... */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.container ul li{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  /* Other format rules here ... */
}
```

If you don't specify the div's height, it will be set by the h2 element's metrics, since absolutely positioned elements don't force the layout. I hope this helps.